how to make ast-grep to support assertion type in typescript?
background
i want to parse this code:
import a from 'b' assert { type: `json` };

problem:
the playground shows ERROR:
ERROR
  identifier
  identifier

expected results:
a better KIND of sturcture
is there any better way to handle this?

Please provide the rules and/or the code you use that gives you this error.
